# In Android populate simple ViewPager Gallery from URL

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've created a simple Image Gallery using ViewPager. Right now, it's grabbing the images from the drawables folder. I'd like to have the ViewPager load the images from an URL. The glitch comes in the Adapter class at `setImageResource`. It won't accept a string variable. So how can I tweak the code so that it can accept the string array? My Code:

```
    //--- Main Activity Class:
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class WCBCGallery51 extends Activity {
Button back_BTN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery5_main);
    back_BTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_gal5_btn);


    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    WCBCGallery5Adapter adapter = new WCBCGallery5Adapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);



}//--- END onCreate

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    // finish();
}

}
```

Here's the Adapter Class:

```
    //--- Adapter Class
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class WCBCGallery51Adapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] { R.drawable.image01,
        R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03, R.drawable.image04,
        R.drawable.image25, R.drawable.image26, R.drawable.image27,
        R.drawable.image28 };

String[] GalImagesStr = {
        "http://www.website.com/images/image01.png",
        "http://www.website.com/images/image02.png",
        "http://www.website.com/images/image03.png",
        "http://www.website.com/images/image04.png",
        "http://www.website.com/images/image25.png",
        "http://www.website.com/images/image26.png",
        "http://www.website.com/images/image27.png",
        "http://www.website.com/images/image28.png" };


WCBCGallery51Adapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return GalImagesStr.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.padding_medium);
    imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    //--- here's where the problem is:
    imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the image and provide a callback to the view so the image can be placed once the download completes.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) example. You can download a complete app example there.